# Is there a way to Fix a Google Maps Marker to the Center of its Map always in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

What i want is I want to fix the marker position to the centre of my map view. when map moves still my marker should stick to that centre point.
Code for marker is shown below:

```
var pin:GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude))
pin.icon = UIImage(named: "img_map_pin")
pin.map = mapView?
pin.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44, 0.44)
mapView?.selectedMarker = pin
```

I want to make same as Uber has done. When map moves marker is in centre and after map stops moving I get that point's address from map.

Answer (score 1):

Assign `GMSMapViewDelegate` to `class` and add below code

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
     pin.position = position.target
 }
```